# Shared Preferences Boolean

Tags: android, boolean, sharedpreferences

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to get a grip on this Shared Preferences method using boolean values. One button is to change the value and the second to read it. But it says that there's a requirement for a (string,int) and I can't figure out where did I make my mistake. Could you please help?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SharedPreferences preference;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
Button btn;
Button btn2;
Context context;
Boolean glowa;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    SharedPreferences preference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean glowa = preference.getBoolean("GLOWA", false);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editor.putBoolean("GLOWA", true);
            editor.apply();

        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences preference;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
            preference = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("GLOWA");
            if (glowa == true) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "true", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "mistake", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you aren't delivering the correct input to one of your functions. Please post your full error message. You need to find out which function is having an issue and determine what required value is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
preference = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("GLOWA");
```

to

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("GLOWA", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedpreferences.getBoolean("GLOWA",false); // return false if key not found in preference file

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("GLOWA", true);
editor.commit();
```

Your desired preferences file name is same as a key of a boolean. It's better to choose two different name.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch from SharedPreferences use the below code:

```
SharedPreference sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedPreferences.getBoolean("key",false);
```

To store data in SharedPreferences use the below code:

```
SharedPreference sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("key", true);
editor.apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix your class and sharedpreferences initialization. I hope this solve your problem to fetch boolean from sharedpreference

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences preference;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Button btn;
    Button btn2;
    Context context;
    Boolean glowa;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

        preference = this.getSharedPreferences("myAppPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                editor.putBoolean("GLOWA", true);
                editor.apply();

            }
        });

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (preference.getBoolean("GLOWA",false)) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "true", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "mistake", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Error:(34, 22) error: no suitable method found for getSharedPreferences(int)
method Context.getSharedPreferences(String,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(String,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)  I got something like this :(

Comment: `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);` or `this.getSharedPreferences("myAppPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`